# Remove duplicate rows from select query using group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a situation to grab rows with a minimum value of a certain column. Below is the image of my made up table to explain what I am trying to do.

[image: Desired rows]

I need to pull one record per instance_oid with the minimum shelf number. I wrote the query like this:

```
select instance_oid, site, bldg, room, min(shelf) group by instance_oid, site, bldg, room, shelf
```

This gives same record in multilpe rows (as many rows as I have for each instance_oid). How do I make sure I get only one record, i.e, the one with the min(shelf) as I highlighted in the attached image?

Comment: You're grouping by shelf, so MIN( shelf ) and MAX( shelf ) will be equal to shelf.  With the sample data above, you'll get two of the first oid because you're also grouping by site ( 1, 4 ).

Comment: Could you please present data in the form of `SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G` and as `INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES(.....)`. This makes it easier to copy and paste and try out solutions.

Comment: @Avarkx, You are correct and I want the shelf with value 1.

Comment: Remove `site, bldg, room` from both the select statement and `shelf` from the group by.  If that's not exactly what you need, then @Vérace looks like he's willing to sort you out if you post some DDL to work with

Comment: What's your sqlmode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**take off shelf at the end of your group by**

```
select instance_oid, site, bldg, room, min(shelf) group by instance_oid, site,  bldg, room
```

Note:
As mentioned in a comment the sites are different (and not highlighted in yellow), but I'm assuming you want newly grouped row output when that happens...

if not I would not include the site data:

```
select instance_oid, bldg, room, min(shelf) group by instance_oid, bldg, room
```

Comment: Got it, thanks! +1 and selected as the answer. I needed to do some sub queries to filter 4 from (1,4) that @Avarkx pointed out.